# Writing to multiple files with fixed number of lines in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I have a generator that generates strings, which I need to write to output files. However, I also need to have each output file contain a fixed number of lines. I also want to do this incrementally. Meaning I don't want to save all lines in the memory and flush them to a file at once, since the desired number of lines for each file could be huge.

I cannot seem to figure out a way to do this with the "with" statement in Python.

Something like:

```
for line in line_generator:
    write_to_output_file(line, _MAX_LINES_PER_FILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will change the target file every `_MAX_LINES_PER_FILE`

```
for i, line in enumerate(line_generator):
    if not i % _MAX_LINES_PER_FILE:
        # open a new output file
        output_file = open(filename_generator(i // _MAX_LINES_PER_FILE), "w")

    print >> output_file, line
```

Comment: As is, your answer leaks file descriptors since the files are never closed.

Comment: The file is being implicitly closed when the new `output_file` is opened (as its ref count goes to zero)

Comment: Will this have a lot of overhead since you are doing a file open for each line?

Comment: @scabbage it is not opening a file on each line, its opening a file each `_MAX_LINES_PER_FILE` lines

Answer (score 0):

You could use itertools.islice if you don't mind storing each section in memory:

```
from itertools import islice


def write_slices(g, n):
    for ind, sli in enumerate(iter(lambda: list(islice(g, n)), []), 1):
        with open("out_{}".format(ind), "w") as f:
            f.writelines(sli)
```

Or just a line at a time:

```
def write_slices(g, n):
    for ind, line in enumerate(g):
        with open("out_{}".format(ind), "w") as f:
            f.write(line)
            f.writelines(islice(g, n-1))
```

Comment: Looks like you are doing a file open+close on a line by line basis. Wouldn't this incur a lot of overhead?

Comment: @scabbage. we only open the file once per section, writelines writes a whole section of lines from the iterable each time

Comment: I mean in the second version of your implementation. I definitely would like to append to the file on a line by line basis.

Comment: @scabbage.  we are writing a line then the whole section of lines using writelines so we open each file once and once only